# Why can't I change the default value of a function after it was defined?

Tags: python

```
i = 5

def f(arg=i):
    print(arg)

i = 6
f()
```

I am learning Python from the official documentation. There I find the above piece of code which I am unable to understand as to why 5 is printed instead of 6. I am relatively new to Python. Can somebody help me understand the concept?

Comment: The default is evaluated when the function is defined, not when it's called.

Comment: Therefore you should pass i to the function to obtain the behavior you expect.

Comment: @Barmar Can you please explain this more? Having shifted from Java, it seems quite strange to me.

Comment: @dspr In the code, the function call is after the updating of value of i to 6. Then why the value is coming 5 instead of 6?

Comment: As explained by Barmar, this is because the default value of `arg` is fixed when the function is declared, not when it is called : `arg` becomes 5 on line 3 and remains 5 even when it's called because no argument was passed to the function (so the default is used). Pass `I`to the function instead and the printed value will be 6.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change default value of optional function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57662072/how-to-change-default-value-of-optional-function-parameter)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`def f(arg=i)` says "make me a function `f` where the default value for `arg` is whatever `i` is right now". At the time of defining the function, `i=5`.

Comment: Better phrasing "make me a function `f` where the default **object** for arg is whatever object `i` refers to right now".  Mutable default objects can actually be altered and it is a surprising side effect to new Python users.

Comment: This is based on the fact that objects are values by reference, and is thus outside the scope of this question. While that's an important note, referring to `i=5` as an object would be misleading.

Comment: Accurate, not misleading.  It's a fundamental issue of Python that should be understood well.

Answer (score 5):

```
i = 5
def f(arg=i)
    print(arg)
```

The `i` is evaluated at the time of definition, so the code above has the same meaning as the code below:

```
def f(arg=5)
    print(arg)
```

This means that, when the function is called without arguments, `arg` will have the value `5`, no matter what the value of `i` is now.

In order to get what you want, just do the following:

```
def f(arg)
    print(arg)

i = 6
f(i)
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the function takes its default value on the first declaration of 'i'.

Change to i=6 on the first line if you want you code to print 6.

Hope I helped !

Answer (score 1):

This is the difference between something being handled by reference vs by value. When you defined the function `f` you told it to set the argument's default value to `i` this is done by value, not by reference, so it took whatever the value of `i` was at that time and set the default for the function to that. Changing the value of `i` after that point does not change the value of `arg`. If you want it to work that way you could do this:

```
i = 5
def f(arg = None):
    if (arg = None)
        arg = i
    print(arg)

i = 6
f()
```

This lets you pass a value for `arg` into the function as normal, but if you don't (or you explicitly pass `None`) it updates `arg` to the current value of `i` if `arg` is still `None` (Python's version of NULL if you're familiar with other languages)

---

Something similar can be done using the `or` operator, `arg = arg or i`,but that will check if `arg` is falsy, and when using integers like you are in your example, 0 will be caught by the check.

Answer (score 1):

What others have said is true...the default is evaluated at the time of function creation, but it is not that it takes the "value of i" at the time of creation.  The default is assigned the *object* referred to by "i" at the time of creation.  This is an important point, because if that object is mutable, the default can be *changed*!

Here's what happens:

```py
import inspect

i = 5   # name "i" refers to an immutable Python integer object of value 5.
print(f'i = {i} (id={id(i)})')  # Note value and ID

# Create function "f" with a parameter whose default is the object
# referred to by name "i" *at this point*.
def f(arg=i):
    print(f'arg = {arg} (id={id(arg)})')

# Use the inspect module to extract the defaults from the function.
# Note the value and ID
defaults = dict(inspect.getmembers(f))['__defaults__']
print(f'defaults = {defaults} (id={id(defaults[0])})')

# name "i" now refers to a different immutable Python integer object of value 6.
i = 6
print(f'i = {i} (id={id(i)})') # Note value and ID (changed!)
f()  # default for function still referes to object 5.
f(i) # override the default with object currently referred to by name "i"
```

Output:

```
i = 5 (id=2731452426672)               # Original object
defaults = (5,) (id=2731452426672)     # default refers to same object
i = 6 (id=2731452426704)               # Different object
arg = 5 (id=2731452426672)             # f() default is the original object
arg = 6 (id=2731452426704)             # f(i) parameter is different object
```

Now see the results of a mutable default:

```
import inspect

i = [5]  # name "i" refers to an mutable Python list containing immutable integer object 5
print(f'i = {i} (id={id(i)})')  # Note value and ID

# Create function "f" with a parameter whose default is the object
# referred to by name "i" *at this point*.
def f(arg=i):
    print(f'arg = {arg} (id={id(arg)})')

# Use the inspect module to extract the defaults from the function.
# Note the value and ID
defaults = dict(inspect.getmembers(f))['__defaults__']
print(f'defaults = {defaults} (id={id(defaults[0])})')

# name "i" now refers to a different immutable Python integer object of value 6.
i[0] = 6  # MUTATE the content of the object "i" refers to.
print(f'i = {i} (id={id(i)})') # Note value and ID (UNCHANGED!)
f()  # default for function still refers to original list object, but content changed!
i = [7]  # Create a different list object
print(f'i = {i} (id={id(i)})') # Note value and ID (changed)
f(i)     # override the default currently refered to by name "i"
```

Output:

```
i = [5] (id=2206901216704)            # Original object
defaults = ([5],) (id=2206901216704)  # default refers to original object
i = [6] (id=2206901216704)            # Still original object, but content changed!
arg = [6] (id=2206901216704)          # f() default refers to orginal object, but content changed!
i = [7] (id=2206901199296)            # Create a new list object
arg = [7] (id=2206901199296)          # f(i) parameter refers to new passed object.
```

This can have strange side effects if not understood well:

```py
>>> def f(a,b=[]):    # mutable default
...   b.append(a)
...   return b
...
>>> x = f(1)
>>> x
[1]
>>> y = f(2)    # some would think this would return [2]
>>> y
[1, 2]
>>> x           # x changed from [1] to [1,2] as well!
[1, 2]
```

Above, `b` refers to the original default list object.  Appending to it mutates the default list.  Returning it makes `x` refer to the same object.  The default list now contains `[1]` so appending in the 2nd call make it `[1,2]`.  `y` refers to the same default object as `x` so both names refer see the same object content.

To fix, make the default immutable and create a new list when the default is seen:

```py
>>> def f(a,b=None):
...   if b is None:
...     b = []
...   b.append(a)
...   return b
...
>>> f(1)
[1]
>>> f(2)
[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are assigning the value when the function is created. `arg` at the time of creation will be defaulted to what `i` is in that moment. Since at the time of the function being created the value of `i` is 5 then that's what the default value of that argument becomes. After the initial creation of the function `i` in the function argument is no longer linked to `i` in the body.